# change block order with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to do this kind of markup? So when the resolution is lower than 640px the container number 2 goes to the bottom.

I know that I should use `@media (max-width:600px) {}`
but I don't really understand how to get the block #2 to bottom from "column right"

Thanks
[image]

My example fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/benderlio/tewzvLxf/3/

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

.column.left {
  width: 60%;
  flex: 0 0 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.column.right {
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
  flex: 0 0 1;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="column left">
    
  </div>

  <div class="column right">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried `@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) `?

Comment: You can't with that html structure (or it will be very hard and hacky)

Comment: @Pete thanks. Any thoughts how to change it?

Comment: Actually you can do it.

Comment: Oh wait theres a changed in the question. It's the same

Comment: Can you elaborate you question, You said you want the container 1 (`column left`?) to go to the bottom and the block #2 (`column right 2nd child`?) to the bottom?

Comment: @Francisaskquestion done. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: This is trivial with `display: grid` but I can't think of a way to do it with `display: flex`.

Answer (score 4):

I would use grid with a media query and removing the column divs:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a b"
    "a c"
    "a d";
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.box1 {
  grid-area: a;
}

.box2 {
  grid-area: b;
}

.box3 {
  grid-area: c;
}

.box4 {
  grid-area: d;
}

@media (max-width:640px) {
  /* adding the commented out areas will allow box1 to keep it's height like in your images so there is a space below box 4 */
  #container {
    /* grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr  1fr; */
    grid-template-areas:
      "a b"
      "a d"
      /* "a ." */
      "c c";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

   <div class="box box1">
     1
   </div>
   <div class="box box2">2</div>
   <div class="box box3">3</div>
   <div class="box box4">4</div>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without changing your structure, like this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  #container {
     flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

You can set the `flex-direction` to have a reverse outcome on columned box.

**EDIT**
So after the confusion was set out, this is the least I can think of to closely produce what you want. You need to set the `container`'s position to be relative and set the `2nd box`'s position to be absolute, but this rather a dirty way to do it.

```css
body {}

#container {
  display: flex;
}

.column.left {
  width: 60%;
  flex: 0 0 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.column.right {
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
  flex: 0 0 1;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  #container {
    position: relative;
  }
  .box:nth-child(2) {
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -100px;
    left: -20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="column left">
    1
  </div>

  <div class="column right">

    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry inserted the answer before editing your question.